# Why BufferedWriter doesn' write all lines in file?

Tags: bufferedwriter, writetofile

This is my code. If I enter 3 lines of text and then type "exit" it will write to file just the last line of text.
What am I missing?
Thanks.

```
`public class WriteFile {
    public static void writeFile() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text;
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        while (!sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                text = sc.nextLine();
                out.write(text);
                out.newLine();

            }
        sc.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you should use the append() method, write remove the last inserted text :

```
public static void writeFile() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = "";
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        while (!(text = sc.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            out.append(text);
            out.newLine();
        }
        sc.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: I tested this code and it worked fine, why did you say it isn't woring ? what's the resut you've got ? do you have an error?